# What's the standard way to avoid constant dereferencing after using `new` keyword?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dereference

The `new` keyword hands you back a pointer to the object created, which means you keep having to deference it - I'm just afraid performance may suffer.

E.g. a common situation I'm facing:

```
class cls {
    obj *x; ...
}

// Later, in some member function:
x = new obj(...);
for (i ...) x->bar[i] = x->foo(i + x->baz);  // much dereferencing
```

I'm not overly keen on reference variables either as I have many `*x`'s (e.g. `*x, *y, *z, ...`) and having to write `&x_ref = *x, &y_ref = *y, ...` at the start of every function quickly becomes tiresome and verbose.

Indeed, is it better to do:

```
class cls {
    obj x; ...    // not pointer
}
x_ptr = new obj(...);
x = *x_ptr;       // then work with x, not pointer;
```

So what's the standard way to work with variables created by `new`?

Comment: both are ok,but you have to remember to delete memory in your second case to avoid leaks...i say it is a personal choice...i use the former method.

Comment: You've got no choice but to keep the pointer if you don't want to leak the object. What you shold do, though, is to avoid `new` completely, unless you've got a good reason to use it.

Comment: Consider using smart pointers

Comment: If in doubt, profile. I guess dereferencing multiple times can be optimized by the compiler and CPU (-> cache), but you cannot avoid some "performance impacts" (as compared to objects of automatic storage duration = stack) since the actual address of the dynamically allocated object (-> `new`) is only known at run-time.

Comment: Why are you using a pointer at all? It's rarely necessary. Your concern over performance is probably misplaced as well -- if you're using that pointer enough to justify it, the compiler will probably put it in a register.

Comment: When i instantiate my class, then if `x` is not a pointer, it will be instantiated as a "default" `obj` object, which I overwrite with a new `obj` almost immediately. In my case, `obj` is quite large which is why I had wanted to avoid this inefficiency.

Comment: @MiloChen: Can you supply the parameters to construct you `obj` correctly in the ctor for `cls`?

Comment: @MiloChen that makes no sense.

Comment: I thought for `obj x; x = obj(...);` the constructor for `obj` would get called twice, and hence inefficient. Also, I thought the 2nd statement would *copy* the `obj` into the existing `x`, which is also inefficient.

Comment: @MiloChen yes, but you can just call `obj x(...)`.

Comment: When converted to assembley the access to an automatic object and a dynamic object look **exactly** the same. Memory access is done via an address and an offset from that address (unless it is optimized into a register and that is way beyond this discussion). A local object is an address a dynamic object is an address the access is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no other way to work with objects created by `new`. The location of the unnamed object created by `new` is always a *run-time* value. This immediately means that each and every access to such an object will always unconditionally require dereferencing. There's no way around it. That is what "dereferencing" actually is, by definition - accessing through a run-time address.

Your attempts to "replace" pointers with references by doing `&x_ref = *x` at the beginning of the function are meaningless. They achieve absolutely nothing. References in this context are just syntactic sugar. They might reduce the number of `*` operators in your source code (and might increase the number of `&` operators), but they will not affect the number of physical dereferences in the machine code. They will lead to absolutely the same machine code containing absolutely the same amount of physical dereferencing and absolutely the same performance.

Note that in contexts where dereferencing occurs repeatedly many times, a smart compiler might (and will) actually read and store the target address in a CPU register, instead of re-reading it each time from memory. Accessing data through an address stored in a CPU register is always the fastest, i.e. it is even faster than accessing data through compile-time address embedded into the CPU instruction. For this reason, repetitive dereferencing of manageable complexity might not have any negative impact on performance. This, of course, depends significantly on the quality of the compiler.

In situations when you observe significant negative impact on performance from repetitive dereferencing, you might try to cache the target value in a local buffer, use the local buffer for all calculations and then, when the result is ready, store it through the original pointer. For example, if you have a function that repeatedly accesses (reads and/or writes) data through a pointer `int *px`, you might want to cache the data in an ordinary local variable `x`

```
int x = *px;
```

work with `x` throughout the entire function and at the end do

```
*px = x;
```

Needless to say, this only makes sense when the performance impact from copying the object is low. And of course, you have to be careful with such techniques in aliased situations, since in this case the value of `*px` is not maintained continuously. (Note again, that in this case we use an ordinary variable `x`, not a reference. Your attempts to replace single-level pointers with references achieve nothing at all.)

Again, this sort of "data cashing" optimization can also be implicitly performed by the compiler, assuming the compiler has good understanding of the data aliasing relationships present in the code. And this is where C99-style `restrict` keyword can help it a lot. But that's a different topic.

In any case, there's no "standard" way to do that. The best approach depends critically on your knowledge of data flow relationships that exist in each specific piece of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Instantiate the object without the `new` keyword, like this:

```
obj x;
```

Or if your constructor for `obj` takes parameters:

```
obj x(...);
```

This will give you an object instead of a pointer thereto.

Comment: that will call copy constructor of `obj`. just `obj x` is enough

Comment: Well, answer like this assume that the original use of `new` was completely unjustified. What made you assume that? The purpose of new (among other things) is to create object with run-time lifetime, run-time type, run-time quantity and so on. So, when someone used `new` it is expected that they used it for a reason. In general it cannot be replaced with a local or static object. So, why are you assuming that the use of `new` was unjustified in this case?

Comment: @AndreyT, the OP wasn't specific. I can't read minds. If the answer helps him, he can accept it. If not, he can accept a different one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide whether you want to allocate your things on heap or on stack. Thats completely your   decision based on your requirements. and there is no performance degradation with dereferencing. You may allocate your `cls` in heap that will stay out of scope and keep instances of `obj` in stack

```
class cls {
  obj x;//default constructor of obj will be called
}
```

and if obj doesn't have a default constructor you need to call appropiate constructor in `cls` constructor